# Python: How can I test my package if it runs on Linux, Mac and Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, macos, testing

I need to test my Python package if it works properly on different systems. I found *Tox* for different Python versions, but what about different operating systems like Windows, Linux and Mac.

Can you recommend me a convenient way to test if my code works on all systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need (possibly virtual) machines running one of each operating system. Personally, I just run my unit tests on different physical machines, but nearly all of my code is operating-system independent, so I can do most of my development on one operating system during the day and just run the tests on the other OSes at the end of the day.

If you have operating-system dependent code (e.g., Windows handles the Python [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) package differently from Unix), you can use the [`unittest` module's skip functionality](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures) to skip tests of, say, Windows behavior when you're running the tests on Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Travis to run tests on Linux, Mac, and Windows. Travis supports these platforms. This is the most convenient option. If the repo is open source, Travis is free.

Update:
All major code management services have their CI/CD tools. You can use them too. e.g. Github runner, Gitlab CI/CD, etc.